# How to create an admin module with Customer Grid

Tags: php, magento

I want to create an admin module with multiple tabs and in that one of tab should have customer Grid.

By using the below article i am able to create Admin module with multiple tabs.

https://www.pierrefay.com/magento-training/admin-grid-magento-tutorial.html

In Tabs.php added the below code and it started giving multiple tabs in my module

```
class Pfay_Films_Block_Adminhtml_Films_Edit_Tabs extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs
  {
     public function __construct()
     {
          parent::__construct();
          $this->setId('films_tabs');
          $this->setDestElementId('edit_form');
          $this->setTitle('Information sur le film');
      }

      protected function _beforeToHtml()
      {
          $this->addTab('form_section', array(
                   'label' => 'About the movie',
                   'title' => 'About the movie',
                   'content' => $this->getLayout()
                                     ->createBlock('pfay_films/adminhtml_films_edit_tab_form')
                                     ->toHtml()
        ));
        
        $this->addTab('customer_section', array(
                   'label' => 'Customer Information',
                   'title' => 'Customer Information',
                   'content' => $this->getLayout()
                                     ->createBlock('pfay_films/adminhtml_films_edit_tab_customer')
                                     ->toHtml()
        ));
        
        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }
}
```

I want my page some thing like this
[image]

How can i achieve this, any suggestions ??

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: @VinodKumar I don't have any error, I am not able to display customer's grid there,, i tried to found similar articles in internet but no use.

Answer (score 0):

in that tab you can render your customer phtml
Follow following path

```
app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\widget\grid.phtml
```

and you will get the idea about that

Answer (score 0):

Go through these two links .. These might come in handy

https://astrio.net/blog/magento-admin-form/

http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-a-custom-grid-from-scratch/